# Timing a moving sprite

Tags: c#, opengl, timing, stopwatch

I need to move my sprite on a path (`List<Point>`track) pixel per pixel in my OpenGL game, so I need to implement a way to control timing. I read about different ways: using `OnRenderUpdate` (but I can't make nothing faster than 1/fps), using a different thread to control time or using a `StopWatch` (instead of a `Timer`). I'm trying with the last one:

```
private void Sprite_Move(Sprite sprite, List<Point> path) {
  track.Clear();
  for (int i = 1; i < path.Count; i++) {
    //memorize all track pixel, so I can update pixel per pixel my sprite position
    Bresenham2(path[i-1], path[i]);
  }
  //moving flag
  sprite.moving = true;
  //start my StopWatch
  timer.Start();
  Loop(timer, sprite);

}

private void Loop(Stopwatch timer, Sprite sprite) {
  int i = 1;
  while (timer.IsRunning) {
    //moving each 0.03s?
    if ((sprite.moving) & (timer.Elapsed.Milliseconds >= 30)) {
      if (i < track.Count) {
        //change sprite position to the i-th track pixel
        Sprite_Position(skinny, track[i]);
        i++;
        timer = StopWatch.StartNew();
        Console.WriteLine("Tick");
      }
      //if I'm on the end of the track I can exit
      else timer.Stop();
    }
  }
}
```

I can't see my sprite moving. Everything is blocked until the last iteration, then I see my sprite on the last pixel of the track...teleport!

Comment: `OnRenderUpdate` is what you should be using.

Comment: if I force my game to run in 30 fps, I can't make a move faster than 1/fps.

Comment: sprite.X = sprite.X + 1; run every 1/30s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of relying on a timer to correctly tick at a certain interval, you can use some sort of global time value instead -- this depends on your framework, or a StopWatch, and look at its elapsed time.

For instance, if you have N steps in your animation, and the animation altogether should take T seconds to run, you would find the correct step for your animation by

```
int frame = (int)((CurrentTimeInSeconds / (float)T) * N)
```

(Do take care of overflows, ie. if the `frame` >= N, don't do anything anymore.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, `StopWatch.Reset()` also stops the timer.
See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.reset%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).
So after the first iteration your timer.IsRunning will be false.

Instead you could use `timer.StartNew()` in your Loop.

Regarding the animation timing: 
I think the StopWatch is ok for the moment. 
Using a StopWatch or a separate Thread gives you independence from your rendering speed.
Although that shouldn't be an issue while you stick to 2D sprites for animation.

From an older Project of mine:

```
    m_LastPoll.Stop();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("{0}:\t{1}", this.VendorID, m_LastPoll.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    m_LastPoll.Reset();
    m_LastPoll.Start();
```

That worked definitely.

Comment: ok it works but I can't see my sprite moving. Just in the final position when my loop finishes to work...

Comment: Hum... Strange. StartNew should work. You could also use "timer.Start();" after the Reset.

Comment: it works but I can't see my sprite moving. Everything is blocked until the loop finishes to work, then my sprite "teleports" himself to the last pixel. I edited the question.

Comment: so it worked before, but now it doesn't? if that's the case, i'm at a loss. What you could try is to use the StopWatch in combination with the above answers. Meaning that you use OnRenderUpdate to update your frame index given the above formula, and the time given by the StopWatch. I'm only familiar with DX, no OpenGL experience, sry.